# Encountering "Xlib: extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0"." when using ZED stereo camera

Tags: drivers, nvidia

After updating ZED stereo camera SDK to 1.1.0 and OpenCV 3.1.0, I run ZED Explorer and have the following error messages in terminal:

```
Xlib: extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib: extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
```

From other discussions, the issue seems caused by Nvidia driver. Here is my Nvidia driver inform:

```
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GK106M [GeForce GTX 765M] [10de:11e2] (rev a1)

Kernel driver in use: nvidia

NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  304.131  Sun Nov  8 21:43:33 PST 2015

GCC version:  gcc version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
```

My machine is Intel integrated GPU + this Nvidia GPU.

Any suggestion to fix this issue?